# my SpriteRender in Unity always null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when i try to get sprite in my project it's always = null, but i don't understand why, i'm trying to GetComponent/GetComponentInChildren, it's same.

Sprite is Child of my Character like here :

[image]

and this is code:

```
new public Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
private Animator animator;
private SpriteRenderer sprite;

private void Amwake()
{
    sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

}


private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal")) Run();
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) Jump();
}

private void Run()
{
    Vector3 direction = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    sprite.flipX = direction.x < 0.0F;
}
```

Comment: Instead of an image, could you write any settings you feel are relevant to the question in the question? If the link breaks, this question may not be helpful anymore in the future.

Comment: okay, next time i will write it, but here no any settings, only sprite with 1 frame, and when i try to get this sprite it is null :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mispelled `Awake`and wrote `Amwake` instead, so Unity3D wouldn't recognize it and it doesn't get called.

Simply rename

```
private void Amwake()
```

to

```
private void Awake()
```

Comment: On a side node, all Unity callbacks such as Awake, Start, Update, OnCollisionEnter etc. are highlighted in blue in visual studio. It should be easy to catch such typo errors if u notice those.

Comment: A simple typo like this one should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Thanks! it's my mistake, now works ( , but i dont understand in debug my rigitbody wasn't null...it was in Amwake too

Comment: Well it was the main culprit here so it does technically answer the question.

Comment: Yeah it did solve the problem by just removing "m" from Awake. This why you can vote to close question as "a simple typographical error."

Comment: @Ingvar It's probably because you dragged your rigidbody onto the field in the unity inspector.

Comment: @Ingvar - I don't see in the code you posted where you actually use the `rigidbody` variable.  You attempt to assign it by calling `GetComponent`, but since you never attempt to use the variable afterwards, the exception is not thrown.